# Get SharePoint 2010 workflow history for a list item

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

Every time I create a list item, a SharePoint 2010 Workflow runs.

This workflow sends an e-mail to a specific user. I've created a page with a CEWP and I would like to show a sort of "log" of e-mails sent by workflow, but I did not find a REST API to get these informations.

For example I would display a list with these informations:

```
- ListItem 1 --> Email sent to address@domain.tld on mm/dd/YYYY at HH:mm 

- ListItem 2 --> Email sent to address@domain.tld on mm/dd/YYYY at HH:mm 
[...]
```

Is there a REST API to call to obtain this data? Even running date-time and status of the workflow should be good for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For the original workflow history, it is a list with the url:

> http://yoursite/Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx

Check more information here:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/voyage/2015/01/23/where-is-workflow-history-list/

You can use it directly in your CEWP. The potential problem is that the list only shows GUID, which is hard to get the idea. and here is a workaround you can try to use:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2012/12/17/workflow-name-in-workflow-history-list/